# Dom4j parsing - How to declare HTML entities programmatically? "The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared."

Tags: java, sax, dom4j

I'm using Dom4j to parse HTML documents.
Dom4j expects XML, so HTML entities are not declared.
It's possible to declare them in document's DTD, but I am parsing external input, so that's not appropriate. I'd rather declare them programmatically in the parser.

Here's my code:

```
    // Read.
    final DocumentFactory df = DOMDocumentFactory.getInstance();
    SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
    Document doc, outDoc;
    try {
        doc = reader.read( new StringReader(htmlStr) );
    }
    catch( Exception ex ){
        throw new RuntimeException("Error parsing the HTML:\n       " + ex.toString() );
    }
```

I see that `SAXReader` has `reader.setEntityResolver( ??? );` but seems like it's not the solution as the overridable method looks like this:

```
public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) throws SAXException, IOException
```

**What I am looking for** is something like

```
reader.setTrueEntityResolver( new EntityResolver(){
    public InputStream resolve( String name ){ ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a possible solution in http://evc-cit.info/dom4j/dom4j_groovy.html
Where it's suggested to add a XML Commons Catalog stuff.

However, that seems like an overkill, as there's no doctype specified anyway, and I only intend to resolve the commons HTML 4 entities.

***Update***: Turned out that without explicit DOCTYPE declaration, this doesn't have any effect - EntityResolver is never called.

Maven dep:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-resolver</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Config in `/CatalogManager.proeprties` on classpath:

```
# allow location to be relative to this file's directory
relative-catalogs=yes

# A semicolon-delimited list of catalog files.
# In this instance, we have a single catalog file, and it's a relative path name
catalogs=sgml-lib/xml.soc

# no debugging messages, please
verbosity=0

# Use the SYSTEM identifier 
prefer=system
```

Tell the parser to use the catalog resolver when it encounters the DTD:

```
cResolver = new CatalogResolver( cMgr )
reader = new SAXReader( )
reader.setEntityResolver( cResolver )
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you said, DOM4J is not meant to parse HTML. I would rather use something like [tagsoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) or [HTML Cleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/). It's just not entities, HTML is not XML.